# Meaning of "whip’s gotta be full-on European luxury"

Tags: meaning

I would like to know the meaning of "whip’s gotta be full-on European luxury" in the context below. Is it something like: the car is going to be full of European luxury goods?

> The minute I started getting smart about my finances was the moment I finally got into the driver’s seat of my life. And you know that if I’m going to drive, then the whip’s gotta be full-on European luxury.

Comment: M.W. What is a whip in slang?
Whip has been used as a slang word for "car" since the late 20th century. It's also used as a verb meaning "to drive (a car)." [...] **then the driving has to be full-on [complete] European luxury**. If the question is not voted for closing, I will enter this as an answer.

Answer (score 5):

A "whip" is a car, often a luxury car and originally a Mercedes-Benz, according to car website [The Drive](https://www.thedrive.com/article/7495/why-is-a-car-called-a-whip):

> For a while, a whip referred specifically to a Mercedes-Benz. ... Eventually, the word became normalized, and now refers to any car on the road.

"Full-on" means "complete" or "full-fledged," according to [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/full-on), so for a car to be "full-on European luxury" means that it's a truly high-end luxury car, i.e. not just a near-luxury or premium-compact model, and from a European manufacturer (such as Mercedes-Benz), not a mere Lexus or Cadillac, which the speaker sees as less glamorous.

In the context of both sentences, the speaker appears to be saying "If I'm going to get smart about my finances, I'm going to do it to the fullest possible extent and get super into the very best investments, fanciest advisors," or whatever they consider the most high-flying, no-expenses-spared approach to finance.

Comment: As who notes? I believe I was the one who noted it.

Comment: [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/whip) gives 'whip' as "*US informal* A car." This is hinted at by the reference to a European model, which of course isn't glamorous for a European (sporting a Cadillac might be), and as a UK native I had to look it up. I note that Lexus, a luxury car from Toyota, doesn't seem to qualify as 'glamorous' at all.

Comment: @Lambie I was referring to the fact that OP had used "car" in paraphrasing the sentence in their question, so it seemed to me they were already familiar with the term (as I was)

Comment: @MissMonicaE Ok, that was not so clear. Apologies.

Comment: @Lambie no worries!

Comment: Please attribute links correctly.